# Update and remove two different table at the same time in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is my code. I want to delete a row from promotion table. But before deleting I want to update `EmpOfficialInformation` table.
When I make save changes, it removes the row but didn't update the `EmpOfficialInformation` table.

```
    public async Task DeleteAsync(EmpPromotionOrDemotion entity)
    {
        var emp = await _context.EmpOfficialInformation
            .Where(e => e.Id == entity.EmployeeId)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        emp.DesignationId = entity.PreviousPositionId;
        emp.TerritoryId = entity.PrevTerritoryId;
        emp.RegionId = entity.PrevRegionId;
        emp.AreaId = entity.PrevAreaId;
        emp.SubTerritoryId = entity.PrevSubTerritoryId;

        _context.EmpOfficialInformation.Update(emp);

        var log = Logger.Log(entity, _httpContextAccessor);
        _context.Logs.Add(log);

        _context.EmpPromotionOrDemotions.Remove(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: `_context.EmpOfficialInformation.Update(emp);`  as EF tracks the entities, this should not even be required. Just save the changes. But it looks as if the `entity` is already tracked. That will point to the same entity as `ent`. So modification of the one will affect the other. You should look into using a (view)model.

Comment: I meant `emp` where I wrote `ent`, but cannot edit it anymore.

Comment: @DarkkL why? `async/await` isn't broken. There's no "just in case". That change will only increase blocking, not help with anything

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below and succeeded:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(M1 m)
    {

        
        var m2 = await _context.M2.FindAsync(m.Id);
        m2.word = m.word;
        m2.errors = m.errors;
        _context.M2.Update(m2);
        _context.M1.Remove(m);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

[image]
Could you show more details of your model  and your database

Comment: Post code as text not images. Images can't be compiled or tested. There shouldn't be any reason to use `Update(m2)`, it's a tracked entity. The animation doesn't offer anything. If you wanted to show that the code works, before/after data or the captured SQL statements would be *far* better